# Are these logos properly attributed to their original users?

Tags: history, marketing

Following picture has been recently [tweeted](https://twitter.com/spencerchen/status/725114098107609089): 
[image]

Are the descriptions in the picture authentic?

Comment: It is only poor, negative evidence but a search through the [USPTO Trademarks for Metrocraft](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/) didn't include that logo. (Had it revealed a logo, it would have been strong positive evidence - hence my search.) The others aren't from the US, so I didn't try them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found evidence that at least two of the four logos in the Tweet were used/created as claimed:

[Stadt Bruhl logo by Anton Stankowski](http://theredlist.com/wiki-2-343-917-1000-view-logo-visual-identity-profile-stankowski-anton.html):

[image]
<sub>(source: [theredlist.com](http://theredlist.com/media/database/graphisme/History/logos_partie_1/anton_stankowski_2/015_anton_stankowski_2_theredlist.png))</sub>

[Azuma Drive-In by Ueda Akisato](https://www.graphis.com/logos/cc1c717c-4b40-11e2-ae70-f23c91dffdec/):

[image]

All four logos were [purportedly displayed](https://twitter.com/spencerchen/status/725118979077861376) in *Trademarks & Symbols of the World: The Alphabet in Design* by Yasaburo Kuwayama. I will verify that at least they appear in that book and that the photo in the tweet wasn't faked.

Comment: Hmmm... Am I allowed to edit in the modern logos these allegedly resemble? It is kind of off-topic for the question, but on-topic for the implication behind the claim - i.e. that they are very similar.

Comment: @oddthinking i had included them but sklivvz said they didn't answer the question. I'd be fine if you added them back (check edit history). It would be fair use, since it's for the purpose of comparison / criticism.

Comment: FWIW, the redlist link doesn't work right now. Alternatively: http://www.logobook.com/logo/stadt-bruhl/

Comment: @Oddthinking Really, it would be "The modern logos that allegedly resemble these."